# Use " in regex expression in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the text inside "" in:

```
_["Some text to get"]
```

So I tried the following in C#:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex(@"_\["(.*?)\"]");
```

This does not compile because of the " inside the regex expression.

The regex expression seems to work: https://regexr.com/3h076

How to fix this?

Comment: Please read [ask] before asking a question, and share your research.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just append the inside of the regex to make a larger string

```
_["Some text to get"]
Regex p = new Regex(@"_\[" + " (.*?)" + "\"]");
```